# MacVim: Thicker font rendering compared to TextMate

Tags: macos, rendering, textmate, macvim

This is bothering me for some time now.
With same source file, same theme (almost) the thickness of text between MacVim and Textmate is different.

I have linked to the screenshot .. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCfS4.png). There are 3 editors in it. Leftmost is sublime v3, middle is MacVim and rightmost is TextMate. The objective is to compare the font thickness. MacVim & sublime text is much thicker whereas TextMate is slicker (and sophisticated .. personal choice :) ). All this is on Mac OS X Mavericks with retina display.

I hope u all see the differences in the screenshot.

Note: for MacVim, toggling the anti-alias option does make some difference but still nothing compared to TextMate.

Questions:

- Is there any configuration in VIM (or Mac OS) which governs the font thickness?
  I am a primarily Vim user, so interested in solutions for VIM
- (Out of curiosity) Why is the rendering different? I would assume that all the editors must be relying on underlying OS APIs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has to do with subpixel antialiasing. Textmate disables this for themes with dark backgrounds: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings#controlling-font-smoothing

for MacVim subpixel antialiasing can be disabled with the terminal command:

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim AppleFontSmoothing -int 0
```

Comment: Cool! I had given hope for any answers and here it is. Much appreciated!! I will give it a try